# C how to print index of array pointer

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, pointer-arithmetic, function-definition

I have a function which contains **for** loop for printing pointer to array **index** and value
but my problem is that i cannot find on the internet how to print index by pointer to array
I have tried many options but it always output adress, value or crash...

```
double func(double*startValueOfArrayPointer,double*endValueOfArrayPointer){   
   double *pointerI;

      for(pointerI=startValueOfArrayPointer+1;pointerI<=endValueOfArrayPointer;pointerI++)
      {
        printf("\n %d value is %.2lf",    ,*pointerI);  
      }
   }
```

i want it to output smth like this:

**1 value is 23.32**
**2 value is 34.65**
**3 value is 1.76**
**...**

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want: `printf(" %d value is %.2lf\n", pointerI - startValueOfArrayPointer, *pointerI);`

Comment: @CraigEstey `%d` is not good for `ptrdiff_t`

Comment: @0___________ Oops, does `%d` --> `%ld` or `%zu` work? Or, just `(int) (pointerI - startValueOfArrayPointer)`?

Comment: @CraigEstey ptrdiff_t is signed - so `zu` is not a good choice. Isn't it? (int) can be too short if we consider a portable code. `td` is the correct one - but many implementations do not support it. So the safest is in this case is `lld`

Comment: @0___________ Yes, [in general] it's signed, but in this use case it's always positive, so `zu` (vs. `zd`) may be okay. I've never seen `td` before--always good to learn new things. Is there ever a case where `sizeof(ptrdiff_t) != sizeof(ssize_t)`?

Comment: @CraigEstey in portable code you can't assume anything which is not in the C standard. I do not understand why to use the wrong format if you can use a more correct one?

Comment: @0___________ Because as you mentioned, `td` may not be supported (and I'd do `td` --> `zd` rather than `lld` as the workaround--as what happens with 128 bit pointers?)

Answer (score 2):

The difference has type of `ptrdiff_t` and the correct way of printing it is:

```
printf("\n %td value is %.2lf",  pointerI - startValueOfArrayPointer  ,*pointerI)
```

or if your implementation does not support `%td`:

```
printf("\n %lld value is %.2lf",  (long long)(pointerI - startValueOfArrayPointer)  ,*pointerI)
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters your function returns nothing though its return type is not `void`.

Also the length modifier `'l'` in the format string has no effect.

Bear in mind that in C indices start from 0. Nevertheless your function can look the following way.

```
void func( const double *first, const double *last )
{
    for ( const double *current = first; current != last; ++current )
    {
        printf( "\n%tu value is %.2f",  current - first + 1, *current );
    }
}
```

Or if you want that outputted indices could be start from a user-specified value then the function can look the following way

```
void func( const double *first, const double *last, size_t initial )
{
    for ( const double *current = first; current != last; ++current )
    {
        printf( "\n%zu value is %.2f",  ( size_t )( current - first + initial ), *current );
    }
}
```

Pay attention to that the pointer `last` shall not be in the range of outputted values. Otherwise it will be difficult to specify an empty range for an array. That is the range is specified like `[first, last )`.

For example if you have an array like

```
double a[N];
```

and want to output all values of the array using the function then the function is called like

```
func( a, a + N );
```

or (if to use the modified function) like

```
func( a, a + N, 1 ); // or func( a, a + N, 0 );
```

Comment: thank you. but now i found out another issue when i put parameter values f.e: 2 and 6 to call function like this                                                                                                printf("Values in the range from 2 to 6 are:%.2lf",func(arrPointer+2,arrPointer+6));          it is always outputting index 12345... but how can i make it output index 23456 ?

Comment: @CptTeemo See my updated answer. In this case the function is called like func( arr + 2, arr + 7, 2 );

Comment: thank you but i forget to say i need this function to have only this 2 parameters, sry i dont want to annoy you...

Comment: @CptTeemo With two parameters the function will be unable to know with which value of the index to start outputting.